# how to send and get URL parameter between JSP and controller

Tags: spring, jsp

I'm new to Spring framework.

This time, I'm trying to send some parameter on URL from jsp to controller.

Here's my code

jsp`

```
<tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${articles}" var="article">
                <tr>

                    <td>${article.num}</td>
                    <td>
                    <a href='/practice/bulletindetail?num=${article.num}'>
                    ${article.title }</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>${article.writer }</td>
                    <td>${article.date }</td>
                    <td>${article.hit }</td>    

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>`
```

in href tag, I added parameter ?num=${article.num} right after bulletindetail`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bulletindetail/{num}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getBulletinDetail(@PathVariable(value="num") String urlData){
    System.out.println("url dta : "+urlData);
    return null;
}
```

I tried to retrieve the data in controller by using {num} at the end of the url.

But it never works

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

### 1. Change your controller to (while keeping your JSP the same):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bulletindetail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getBulletinDetail(@RequestParam("num") String urlData){
    System.out.println("url dta : "+urlData);
    return null;
}
```

Or

### 2. change your query url in JSP to (while keeping your controller same)

```
<a href='/practice/bulletindetail/${article.num}'>
```